# Add icon with title in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am using `CoordinatorLayout` to get this effect :

[image: This is screenshot of the same app on iOS]

Here is the layout code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorRootLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/android_appbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayoutAndroidExample"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff"
                app:collapsedTitleGravity="left"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@color/card_outline"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="32dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="48dp">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/parallax_header_imageview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/orange_triangle"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.8"/>


                <ImageView
                    app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/someImage"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/circle"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="-1"
                    />
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:background="@color/off_white"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridview_parallax_header"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:columnWidth="100dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here is what I am getting as output
How can use an icon with the title text?

[image]

Comment: Check this blog with Custom Behaviors http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Comment: yes @SANAT i tried that too as i mentioned but how can i put an icon with the text. please

Comment: Where is "My App Title" text set?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may try the following

[Reference for Co-Ordinator Layout](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/03/android-tip-custom-coordinatorlayout.html)

Now inside your `MainActivity.java`

```
private void handleToolbarTitleVisibility(float percentage) {
    if (percentage >= PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_TITLE_AT_TOOLBAR) {

        if(!mIsTheTitleVisible) {
            startAlphaAnimation(textviewTitle, ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION, View.VISIBLE);
            toolbar.setAlpha(0.9f);
            toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.Primary)));
            mIsTheTitleVisible = true;
        }
    } 
    else {
        if (mIsTheTitleVisible) {
            startAlphaAnimation(textviewTitle, ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION, View.INVISIBLE);
            toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
            mIsTheTitleVisible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: Keep the toolbars background transparent when expanded.**

Comment: I done a long work-around and yes i got what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can take reference from this example:-

[android ParallaxHeaderViewPager](https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager)

Comment: no its not what i m looking for. its not working with gridview

Comment: https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample     try this one  its working for me

Comment: @Pawantpreet this is also not. I've tried this as well.

Answer (score 1):

May be this solve your problem :

You can position the expanded title wherever you want by using these `CollapsingToolbarLayout` attributes:

```
app:expandedTitleGravity        default is bottom|left -or- bottom|start
app:expandedTitleMargin
app:expandedTitleMarginBottom
app:expandedTitleMarginStart
app:expandedTitleMarginEnd
```

Code for layout File :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bgheader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@drawable/sunflowerpic"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/MyToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Then in your java file SetTitle:

```
 CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapse_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Title");
```

Add icon to Top corner :
use `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` with ImagView. For e.g.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/someImage"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/someDrawable"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />
```

Reference to this  link [Collapsing Toolbar Example](http://www.feelzdroid.com/2015/08/collapsing-toolbars-android-example.html)

Comment: please read my question correctly i need an imageview with the title.

Comment: and how i add an small icon that will animate with the title from centre to toolbar. as you can see the image. in the second image you can see the image added but its going to top when scrolling i just want image with the title.

Comment: i've written this code if you can see. would you focus on adding an icon? please

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try [Childs and dependencies](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator)

```
      public boolean onDependentViewChanged(     
      CoordinatorLayout parent, 
      CircleImageView avatar, 
      View dependency) {     

      modifyAvatarDependingDependencyState(avatar, dependency);
   }

   private void modifyAvatarDependingDependencyState(
    CircleImageView avatar, View dependency) {
        //  avatar.setY(dependency.getY());
        //  avatar.setBlahBlat(dependency.blah / blah);
    }
```

http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/03/android-tip-custom-coordinatorlayout.html

[CollapsingToolbarLayout with a custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883693/collapsingtoolbarlayout-with-a-custom-view)

Comment: i tried that code but in that the toolbar is in lower side.

Comment: see my edited answer,i suggest that try to follow that,and you need to change for toolbar

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin

```
    private fun handleToolbarTitleVisibility(percentage: Float) {
    if (percentage >= PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_TITLE_AT_TOOLBAR) {
        if (!mIsTheTitleVisible) {
            startAlphaAnimation(textviewTitle, ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION, View.VISIBLE)
            toolbar.alpha = 0.9f
            toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(resources.getColor(R.color.Primary)))
            mIsTheTitleVisible = true
        }
    } else {
        if (mIsTheTitleVisible) {
            startAlphaAnimation(textviewTitle, ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION, View.INVISIBLE)
            toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(resources.getColor(android.R.color.transparent)))
            mIsTheTitleVisible = false
        }
    }
}
```