# CollapsingToolbarLayout with a customised behavior

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am following this popular [link](https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample) for cordinator behaviour, following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883693/collapsingtoolbarlayout-with-a-custom-view) .
I wanted a desired behavior that image should be floated to right side instead of left and for this, I modified

```
AvatarImageBehavior.java -> maybeInitProperties() method ->
```

as following :

```
if (mFinalXPosition == 0)
            mFinalXPosition= getScreenWidth()-70;
```

**Now I wish the toolbar to be fixed at top, and only image to move and stick to it.**
As per my understanding, only Behavior file is responsible for this transition.
I tried too many things, but not getting and proper approach / call back to proceed.
Any solution/ approach/ different sample is most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the **first** thing you should do is to tweak the layout file - make `Toolbar` fixed at top by removing its `layout_anchor` attribute.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.imageview.placeholder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/quila2"
                android:tint="#11000000"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="24dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:contentPadding="16dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:text="@string/lorem"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:title="">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main.textview.title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/quila_name2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/quila"
        app:border_color="@android:color/white"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:finalHeight="@dimen/image_final_width"
        app:layout_behavior="saulmm.myapplication.AvatarImageBehavior"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

***Note***, I've also removed `main.framelayout.title` section, as I consider it as a part of a `Toolbar` as well. And I've also removed `onOffsetChanged()` and all relative to it methods in `MainActivity`, and made our title of `Toolbar` always visible.

**Secondly**, of course, you should make changes in the `AvatarImageBehavior` class. The main thing here is that now your `ImageView` is dependent on `NestedScrollView` instead of `Toolbar`. But since we're not dependent on `Toolbar` anymore, we still need it to define the `mFinalYPosition`, so I've added the method to find the `Toolbar` as well. Here is the behavior:

```
public class AvatarImageBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<CircleImageView> {

    private final static float MIN_AVATAR_PERCENTAGE_SIZE   = 0.3f;
    private final static int EXTRA_FINAL_AVATAR_PADDING     = 80;

    private final static String TAG = "behavior";
    private Context mContext;

    private float mCustomFinalYPosition;
    private float mCustomStartXPosition;
    private float mCustomStartToolbarPosition;
    private float mCustomStartHeight;
    private float mCustomFinalHeight;

    private float mAvatarMaxSize;
    private float mStartPosition;
    private int mStartXPosition;
    private float mStartToolbarPosition;
    private int mStartYPosition;
    private int mFinalYPosition;
    private int mStartHeight;
    private int mFinalXPosition;
    private float mChangeBehaviorPoint;

    public AvatarImageBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        mContext = context;

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.AvatarImageBehavior);
            mCustomFinalYPosition = a.getDimension(R.styleable.AvatarImageBehavior_finalYPosition, 0);
            mCustomStartXPosition = a.getDimension(R.styleable.AvatarImageBehavior_startXPosition, 0);
            mCustomStartToolbarPosition = a.getDimension(R.styleable.AvatarImageBehavior_startToolbarPosition, 0);
            mCustomStartHeight = a.getDimension(R.styleable.AvatarImageBehavior_startHeight, 0);
            mCustomFinalHeight = a.getDimension(R.styleable.AvatarImageBehavior_finalHeight, 0);

            a.recycle();
        }

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        bindDimensions();
    }

    private void bindDimensions() {
        mAvatarMaxSize = mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_width);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, CircleImageView child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof NestedScrollView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, CircleImageView child, View dependency) {
        maybeInitProperties(parent, child, dependency);

        final int maxScrollDistance = (int) (mStartToolbarPosition);
        float expandedPercentageFactor = dependency.getY() / maxScrollDistance;

        if (expandedPercentageFactor < mChangeBehaviorPoint) {
            float heightFactor = (mChangeBehaviorPoint - expandedPercentageFactor) / mChangeBehaviorPoint;

            float distanceXToSubtract = ((mStartXPosition - mFinalXPosition)
                    * heightFactor) + (child.getHeight()/2);
            float distanceYToSubtract = ((mStartYPosition - mFinalYPosition)
                    * (1f - expandedPercentageFactor)) + (child.getHeight()/2);

            child.setX(mStartXPosition - distanceXToSubtract);
            child.setY(mStartYPosition - distanceYToSubtract);

            float heightToSubtract = ((mStartHeight - mCustomFinalHeight) * heightFactor);

            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = (int) (mStartHeight - heightToSubtract);
            lp.height = (int) (mStartHeight - heightToSubtract);
            child.setLayoutParams(lp);
        } else {
            float distanceYToSubtract = ((mStartYPosition - mFinalYPosition)
                    * (1f - expandedPercentageFactor)) + (mStartHeight/2);

            child.setX(mStartXPosition - child.getWidth()/2);
            child.setY(mStartYPosition - distanceYToSubtract);

            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = (int) (mStartHeight);
            lp.height = (int) (mStartHeight);
            child.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void maybeInitProperties(CoordinatorLayout parent, CircleImageView child, View dependency) {
        if (mStartYPosition == 0)
            mStartYPosition = (int) (dependency.getY());

        View toolbar = tryFindToolbarInLayout(parent);

        if (mFinalYPosition == 0 && toolbar != null) {
            mFinalYPosition = (toolbar.getHeight() / 2);
        }

        if (mStartHeight == 0)
            mStartHeight = child.getHeight();

        if (mStartXPosition == 0)
            mStartXPosition = (int) (child.getX() + (child.getWidth() / 2));

        if (mFinalXPosition == 0)
            mFinalXPosition = dependency.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels - mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_content_inset_material)
                    - ((int) mCustomFinalHeight / 2);

        if (mStartToolbarPosition == 0)
            mStartToolbarPosition = dependency.getY();

        if (mChangeBehaviorPoint == 0 && toolbar != null) {
            mChangeBehaviorPoint = (child.getHeight() - mCustomFinalHeight) / (mStartYPosition - mFinalYPosition - toolbar.getHeight());
        }
    }

    private View tryFindToolbarInLayout(CoordinatorLayout parent) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof Toolbar)
                return child;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");

        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is what I managed to do:

[image]

Comment: thanks rom4ek.  I will try and mark it as answer when it works!

Comment: that works perfect almost. only I am getting a issue intermmitently.http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=43364424783018665227