# Collapsing layout during scrolling in Android

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, coordinator-layout, nestedlayout

I would like to have custom view collapsed with a transition during scrolling.

I have `AppBarLayout` with a `Toolbar` inside. Below that there is a custom view that I want to collapse.

Below custom view there is a `NestedScrollView` with `LinearLayout`.

Toolbar is green, custom layout is pink and scroll with linear is gray:

[image: toolbar custom view and]

After scrolling down:

[image: scrolled down]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="center">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include
            layout="@layout/linear"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Should I go with custom behavior and `CoordinatorLayout` or translation with `NestedScroll` with translation animation?

Comment: As for me, I would wrap your custom view into `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and go with custom behavior. Or you might want to use `OnOffsetChangedListener` of `AppBarLayout` for this transition as well.

Comment: @rom4ek would it be possible to have two image views placed in custom place on `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Comment: You can keep them in the same `RelativeLayout` that you have right now. Just place this `RelativeLayout` inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Comment: @rom4ek but upper toolbar (that with drawer) remains intact, and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is meant to be used inside `AppBarLayout`

Comment: yes, you're right. But you don't need to keep the toolbar inside `AppBarLayout`. You can pull it out of `AppBarLayout`, and place right after `AppBarLayout` in your xml. So your `AppBarLayout` will just contain a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with your custom view inside. Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44647978/3225458, it's not exactly what you want to achieve, but you can understand the xml structure from it, at least.

Comment: @rom4ek yes, then I can use behaviors, but unexpected side efect is that  my toolbar loses functionalities of clicking in up button and shadow that should be under toobar is shown under system window at top

Comment: @rom4ek - I figured it out. You need to wrap this `Toolbar` into additional `AppBarLayout`

Comment: cool, glad to help. I'd try to implement this behavior, but don't have enough time right now:(

Comment: @rom4ek you have library for such things? :)

Comment: No, I don't have such a library, but have some plans for it now:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148326/discussion-between-pixel-and-rom4ek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do this without any library. The key was to have two app bar layouts - one with a placeholder and collapsing toolbar layout that was hidden under custom view, and the second normal one.

Then I've created two behaviors - one for changing nested layout height and second to manipulate inner views inside custom view.

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vieItemDetailsPlaceholder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/second_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/second_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/detailContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="com.example.detail.view.Det ailScrollBehavior">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<!-- second layout with behavior -->
<include layout="@layout/two_circles_layout" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

DetailScrollBehavior:

```
public class DetailScrollBehavior extends Behavior<NestedScrollView> {

    private final Context context;

    public DetailScrollBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, NestedScrollView child, View dependency) {
        return dependency.getId() != R.id.ablItemDetailsSecondToolbar && dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, NestedScrollView child, View dependency) {
        int minHeight = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.some_min_height);
        int placeholderHeight = getPlaceholderHeight(dependency);
        int actionBarHeight = getActionBarHeight(context.getTheme());

        if (placeholderHeight < minHeight + actionBarHeight) {
            placeholderHeight = minHeight + actionBarHeight;
        }

        child.setPadding(0, placeholderHeight, 0, 0);

        return true;
    }
}
```

and part of `two_circles_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relDetailsContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/team_vs_details_height"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_behavior="com.example.DetailBehavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_item_detail">


    [ ... ]

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please post the two_circles_layout.xml content and custom behaviors?

Comment: do you have any tutorial video / written in to learn this stuff? I've been looking for a long time?

Comment: can you the resource to the lines:
- (app:layout_behavior="com.example.detail.view.DetailScrollBehavior")
- (layout="@layout/content")
- (layout="@layout/two_circles_layout")                     All of them gives errors :(

Comment: @LidorEliyahuShelef added

Comment: @pixel in the `two_circles_layout` in the `[ . . . ]` area what was meant to be? I mean is it the start layout or the final layout or it's the layout youre moving his view inside and changing them?

Comment: Those layout elements like circles etc, I redacted them since they are not key of the answer

Comment: It is key b/c the `DetailScrollBehavior`  have red errors, and we need to know which one means what, and also the `DetailScrollBehavior`  doesn't recognizes the `getPlaceholderHeight` and the `getActionBarHeight` methods.
plus you didnt say what the `@layout/content` b/c it gives and error there also

Answer (score 1):

Use Observable ScrollView library
https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView